# "no route to host" / "host is down" cycle

Tags: network, wifi

I'm working on an application that uses UDP-broadcast for discovery. For what it's worth, I'm using ZeroMQ's pure-java implementation project, JeroMQ (but I don't think this is germane to the problem).

I've noticed something strange when I run the application on my Mac -- It will send the broadcast once per second a few times without issue, and then I will get a NoRouteToHost exception, followed by 15-25 seconds of SocketException with the message "host is down". Then the broadcast will go through for another 4-10 seconds. The exact number of successes and failures in the cycle fluctuates a bit, but it's always roughly 5 successes followed by roughly 20 failures.

I have also observed this pattern by using the OSX native ping utility targeting any address on my subnet that doesn't respond to icmp (including [/24 subnet].255) -- A handful of "request timeout" responses (as expected) followed by exactly one "No route to host" and then a couple dozen "host is down" messages. Eventually I get another half-dozen timeouts without connection errors and the cycle repeats.

I observe this behavior on a conventional Access Point 802.11 network, and also an ad-hoc wifi network.

This issue does not happen from a Debian VM or from a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Stretch.

OSX version 10.13.4

I've looked around online some with no success, perhaps because I'm having trouble phrasing the question?